# Cannot read property of "classList" of Null when trying to append text to a DIV in Else If

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am creating a card game in which the user will chose 3 cards and then the cards picked are added to an array called "chosenCards". I am then printing out the cards accordingly to their index number into a new DIV. I want to be able to say basically "if the chosenCard[0] has a div class of 'card1' then print out "some text" to the DIV.

I tried to accomplish this various ways but could not figure out how to compare the div within the array or a way to use switch cases.

I ended up trying to add the card to a div then check if the div contains the class of the card in it & if it does print out "some text" but that did not work as it gives me an error "cannot read property 'classList' of null".

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

**I changed the code to search for the child elements by doing :**

`if(document.querySelector("#cardResults .card1").classList.contains("card1"))`

However when I add an else to it the same error occurs again. 
This is the code that is breaking it now :

```
         document.getElementById("re").innerHTML = "The Hermit suggests that you are in a phase of introspection where you are drawing your attention inwards and looking for answers within. You are in need of a period of inner reflection, away from the current demands of your position.";
         }
         else if(document.querySelector("#cardResults .card2").classList.contains("card2")){
           document.getElementById("re").innerHTML = "You are a fool";
         }

         else {
          document.getElementById("re").innerHTML = "error";
         }
```

I expect the results to look something like this :

Results

How you feel about yourself:

[the hermit card]  : "some text"

Comment: It is because `cardResults` is not a class it's an id. Use `querySelector('#cardResults')` instead.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn good catch! I just tried it and that did not work either though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

classList is a list of classes appended to the element, so it would work if you had `#cardResults.card1`. Instead you want to use `if(document.querySelector("#cardResults .card1"))` as you are searching for the class amongst the child elements.

Comment: did not think about the child elements. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason when I put this in an if else it does not work again...

Comment: @Chris if you just copied from my answer it might be because I didn't close the bracket, edited the answer

Comment: @Chris for what I see you don't need `.classList.contains("card1")` - if ".card1" wasn't found then it will return a falsy value anyway.

Comment: just tried it and it worked! Thank you. I'm assuming its not needed since its already being targeted in the querySelector?

Comment: @Chris exactly like that!